# Promoting warm standby to master with Postgresql 9.4 using streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup, high-availability

I've currently got 2 database servers running Centos 6 and Postgresql 9.4 (identical clones on the same network). They are set up as a primary and a backup created using `pg_basebackup` from the primary, with the primary copying WAL to the secondary's file system and the backup set to update from the WAL and connect to the primary using streaming replication.

This all works fine up to the point that I kill the master and try to promote the backup to be the new master. I'm running `kill -9` to simulate a catastrophic failure of the master and then touching the trigger file on the backup shortly afterwards.

The problem is that as soon as I touch the trigger file on the backup server it detects it and then fails to start up as the primary.

Here are the logs from the backup at the point I disconnect it from the primary:

```
< 2015-10-05 14:20:52.888 BST >LOG:  trigger file found: /tmp/psql.trigger
< 2015-10-05 14:20:52.888 BST >LOG:  redo is not required
< 2015-10-05 14:20:52.904 BST >LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000004" from archive
< 2015-10-05 14:20:52.906 BST >PANIC:  record with zero length at 0/40000C8
< 2015-10-05 14:20:52.906 BST >LOG:  startup process (PID 3101) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
< 2015-10-05 14:20:52.906 BST >LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
< 2015-10-05 14:21:08.580 BST >LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2015-10-05 13:50:08 BST
< 2015-10-05 14:21:08.580 BST >HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
< 2015-10-05 14:21:08.935 BST >LOG:  entering standby mode
< 2015-10-05 14:21:08.947 BST >LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000004" from archive
< 2015-10-05 14:21:08.949 BST >LOG:  record with zero length at 0/40000C8
< 2015-10-05 14:21:08.951 BST >FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "192.168.56.101" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The logs at 13:50 were just the server starting up in recovery mode.

The config in `postgresql.conf` on the primary is:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = archive
max_wal_senders = 2
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p postgres@192.168.56.102:/apps/pgsql/9.4/write_ahead_logs/%f'
archive_timeout = 600
```

The config in `recovery.conf` on the backup is:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.56.101 port=5432 user=backups password=abc'
restore_command = 'cp /apps/pgsql/9.4/write_ahead_logs/%f %p'
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /apps/pgsql/9.4/write_ahead_logs %r'
trigger_file = '/tmp/psql.trigger'
```

I'm sure there's something important I'm missing but after searching the internet and the docs I can't put my finger on it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *I'm running kill -9 to simulate a catastrophic failure of the master*. You should be using `pkill` so you kill all the child backends too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The issue was that I had Monit running in the background which was picking up the backup database before I had written recovery.conf (the servers are being provisioned by chef).

The solution was to pass the -R flag to `pg_basebackup` in order to ensure the database was never started outside of recovery mode which caused it to be incompatible with the WALs and streaming replication from the master.